# How to SSH into running docker container from jenkins execute shell

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, ssh, docker

I am running a docker container (`dind`) from jenkins execute shell

`CONTAINER_ID="$(sudo docker run --privileged -i -d jpetazzo/dind)"`

To execute docker commands inside container I get into container shell

`sudo docker exec -it --privileged ${CONTAINER_ID} bash`

and than I am trying to execute these commands inside `dind` container.

`sudo docker pull hubuser/hello-world`

`sudo docker run hubuser/hello-world`

`sudo docker tag imageId hubuser/hello-world:123`

`sudo docker login --username=hubuser --password=password`

`sudo docker push hubuser/hello-world`

All of these 7 commands I have written in jenkins execute shell. Below given 5 commands are executing outside `dind` container, not inside. If I am trying from terminal than it is attaching to the container shell and executing properly. I want to execute them inside container but from jenkins. I also tried adding `exec` before every command like this:

`sudo docker exec -it --privileged ${CONTAINER_ID} sudo docker pull hubuser/hello-world`

`sudo docker exec -it --privileged ${CONTAINER_ID} sudo docker run hubuser/hello-world`

and so on. This executes commands inside `dind` container but all commands executes in parallel, so before pulling and running the `hello-world` image, it tries to tag it and push it. There it is not finding any `hello-world` image to tag and it does't do anything.

I want all my below 5 commands to execute serially inside `dind` container, that too from jenkins execute shell.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your post is "how to ssh into running docker". I just want to point out this article, wrote by a Docker engineer: [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

After I read your post, that is not treating issue with ssh, I just thought about: why not execute a bash-script that does sequentially what you wanted to?

I'm not sure if I understood well btw, is Jenkins inside a docker? Are you running a docker in a docker?

Comment: Jenkins is not inside docker and Yes I want to build and run docker inside docker using jenkins. I am also thinking of using a calling a bash script. 
And also another way to do that I guess is in your base Dockerfile itself you pull and run another docker, so when we build our first docker it will automatically spin up another docker inside it. Will that be a correct way  ?? Because if we want to do some more stuff inside it than we have to make a very big Dockerfile.